# Use Android to control HP printers via Socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, printing

Now through the Socket connected to the printer, the data transfer is successful, the light shows the accepted data, the printer starts to sound, but stopped after receiving data, and did not print.

The printer model is HP LaserJet 1020.

What should I do?

What can I check the information?

Socket code:

```
public class Test {
    private static final String TAG = "PrinterTest";
    private static final int mNetReceiveTimeout = 1500;
    private static Socket mSocket;

    public static void test() {
        try {
            Log.e(TAG,"Start connecting");
            InetSocketAddress mIneptSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("10.10.254.12", 9100);
            mSocket = new Socket();
            mSocket.connect(mIneptSocketAddress);
            mSocket.setSoTimeout(mNetReceiveTimeout);
            Log.e(TAG,"Start transmission");
            OutputStream os = mSocket.getOutputStream();
            byte[] printerMessage = "Test Android Printer!".getBytes();
            os.write(printerMessage, 0, printerMessage.length);
            os.flush();
            mSocket.close();
            Log.e(TAG,"End");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            //Connection failed
            Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(ioe));
        }
    }
}
```

I make sure the printer is good, there is no problem with the computer-controlled printing.

Comment: If you wanted it to print an image then what would you send?

Comment: If you wanted it to print text in the middle of a page then what would you send?

Comment: If you wanted the text to be red then what would you send?

Comment: If you wanted the text to be bold then what would you send?

Comment: If you wanted it to eject the page then how would you do that?

Comment: Sending print jobs over the network is not just dumping data to the printer´s network interface. Have a look at the printer´s documentation, it should support LPD (Unix) printing and others. Or print form your OS and capture the network data to get an idea how stuff works

Comment: Now I just do not know what to send, I consulted hp staff,  they told me that this thing is private, does not provide relevant information ..... It seems I can only use WIFI printers or computers to provide interface control print.

Comment: Why not use the in-OS printing features: https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html?

Comment: Because the phone can not search the printer, now through the pc relay processing print jobs